# Regex for detecting keys in the yaml file

Tags: python, regex, yaml

I am writing a regex to detect the exposed passwords/secrets/keys in a yaml file.  Below is the example of the yaml file. The `data` key is common to all my yaml files. subkeys under the `data` key will vary for each file.

**Scenario 1:**

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
    PASSWORD: mypass123
    USER: {$USER_NAME}
metadata:
    Timestamp: 2021-03-31T14:29:09Z
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
    DATABASE: {$DATABASE_NAME}
    USER: {$USER_NAME}
    API_KEY: mykey456=
metadata:
    Timestamp: 2021-03-31T14:29:09Z
```

As you can see above sensitive information is exposed for the keys `PASSWORD` & `API_KEY`. I need a regex to match the `data` key & exposed values of sensitive information.

```
import re
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml_str = """\
apiVersion: v1
data:
    PASSWORD: mypass123
    USER: {$USER_NAME}
metadata:
    Timestamp: 2021-03-31T14:29:09Z
"""

regex = r'data:\s*-\s*\b[a-z0-9_ .\-,]:([a-z0-9=_\-]{1,4096})'
```

I have tried the above regex but it is not working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1) Why write a regex to detect the data key if that's not the part that contains sensitive info? Why not write a regex to detect PASSWORD and DATABASE? 2) Why not parse the yaml file and look for secrets in the parsed version?

Comment: If you want to capture the whole block after `data:` from the start of the string in group 1 `^data:((?:\n[^\S\n]{4}[^\s:]+:.*)*)` https://regex101.com/r/7ODHDm/1

Comment: @NickODell There are also other keys in the yaml file, but sensitive information is only under the  `data` key. If any of sub-keys values below the `data` keys are exposed then the regex should match this criteria.

Comment: How did you try that regex?

Answer (score 2):

What about just adding a list of keys that you think may be sensitive -- I don't think they would vary too widely? As an example:

- [`(PASSWORD|DATABASE|other-sensitive-keys-here):\s*([^\n]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/eQIT1A/2)

[image]

However, if you just want to grab the contents within the `data:` section, then I think @Thefourthbird has a good approach. Or even better, parse the yaml file itself.

Comment: It does get the values in 2 capture groups, but it is not related to the `data` key

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that YAML parsing is going to be much easier and more maintainable. For example:

```
import yaml

yaml_str = """\
apiVersion: v1
data:
    PASSWORD: mypass123
    USER: username123
metadata:
    Timestamp: 2021-03-31T14:29:09Z
"""

try:
    data = yaml.safe_load(yaml_str)
except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
    # handle exception ...
    pass

for field_of_interest in ["PASSWORD", "USER"]:
    print(data["data"][field_of_interest])
```